# How can I efficiently "remap" an image?

Tags: performance-tuning, image-processing

Many image processing libraries like [OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/remap/remap.html), [Intel Performance Primitives](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/504403) or [Octave](http://octave.sourceforge.net/image/function/imremap.html) have a useful function called "remap", that takes an image, an array with X coordinates and an array with Y coordinates, and returns an image that "transforms" the image by that geometric mapping. Or, as the IPP documentation puts it: *"Pixel remapping is performed using `pxMap` and `pyMap` buffers to look-up the coordinates of the source image pixel that is written to the target destination image pixel:*

> `dst_pixel[i, j] = src_pixel[pxMap[i, j], pyMap[i, j]]`

The closest thing in Mathematica that I'm aware of is `ImageTransformation`, but that takes a function, not an array. Using arrays can often save a lot of time (for example, you can apply the same mapping-array to multiple image, and arithmetic operations on arrays are very fast).

The best I've come up with so far is to combine `ImageTransformation` and `ListInterpolation` to convert the arrays to functions:

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];
mapX = Table[i + j, {i, 500}, {j, 500}];
mapY = Table[i - j, {i, 500}, {j, 500}];
```

(Imagine some time-consuming operation here. I know that passing `i + j, i - j` as a function to `ImageTransformation` is probably much faster in this simple case, but that's not the point.)

```
{xFn, yFn} = 
  ListInterpolation[#, {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, InterpolationOrder -> 1] & /@ {mapX, mapY};

Timing[ImageTransformation[img, {xFn @@ #, yFn @@ #} &, {500, 500}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, DataRange -> Full]]
```

This works, but is extremely slow (4.7 s on my PC).

The second idea I had was to use `ListInterpolation` on the image directly (in this case, only on the red channel):

```
redFn = ListInterpolation[ImageData[img][[All, All, 1]], 
   InterpolationOrder -> 1];    
Timing[Image[redFn[mapY, mapX]]]
```

This takes 1.7 s for one color channel, so it's even slower for 3 channels.

For comparison: The IPP's remap function usually takes a few milliseconds.

Comment: Very good question! Ages time ago I ended up generating scripts for [mathmap](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/schani/mathmap/) with Mathematica to do similar things. Quite horribly, too...

Comment: Doesn't [ImageTransformation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageTransformation.html) do the same thing? "ImageTransformation[image,function] 
gives an image in which each pixel at position {x,y} corresponds to the position function[{x,y}] in image."

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov: Basically, the function I'm looking for is to `ImageTransformation` what `ListPlot` is to `Plot`: Does the same thing, but with an array of data instead of a function to generate the data.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Perhaps something like this may do. Convert the `mapX` and `mapY` arrays to a 1D list of index values corresponding to position in the *flattened* image data. A 1D list of positions can be used very quickly with `Part`, and the 2D image reconstructed using `Partition`

```
imagemap[img_, mapX_, mapY_] := Module[{a, b, mx, my, id, pix},
  {a, b} = ImageDimensions[img];
  mx = Clip[mapX, {1, a}];
  my = Clip[mapY, {1, b}];
  id = Flatten[ImageData[img], 1];
  pix = Flatten[Transpose[(my - 1) a + mx]];
  Image@Partition[id[[pix]], Length[mx]]]
```

Comment: Nice use of `Clip`, with padding a default value could easily be achieved.

Answer (score 17):

Straightforward method without interpolation, takes 0.1s but it feels like there is lots of room for improvement. I used the definition with `dst_pixel` so the orientation is different from result in question.

I don't know of a quick way to have `Extract` or `Part` return a default value for indices that are out of range so I ended up using `Compile` instead:

```
cImageRemap = 
  Compile[{{data, _Real, 3}, {pxMap, _Integer, 2}, {pyMap, _Integer, 2}},
   Block[{
     nx, ny, nc,
     newdata,
     indx, indy
     },
    {nx, ny, nc} = Dimensions[data];
    newdata = Table[0., {nx}, {ny}, {nc}];
    Do[
     indx = pxMap[[ix, iy]];
     indy = pyMap[[ix, iy]];
     If[1 <= indx <= nx && 1 <= indy <= ny,
      newdata[[ix, iy]] = data[[indx, indy]]
      ];
     , {ix, nx}, {iy, ny}];
    newdata
    ]];

ImageRemap[img_Image, pxMap_?(MatrixQ[#, IntegerQ] &), pyMap_?(MatrixQ[#, IntegerQ] &)] /; 
  Dimensions[pxMap] == Dimensions[pyMap] == ImageDimensions[img] :=
 Image@cImageRemap[ImageData@img, pxMap, pyMap]

img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];
mapX = Table[i + j, {i, #1}, {j, #2}] & @@ ImageDimensions[img];
mapY = Table[i - j, {i, #1}, {j, #2}] & @@ ImageDimensions[img];
Timing[ImageRemap[img, mapX, mapY];]
(* 0.1s *)
```

Edit: With `CompilationTarget->"C"` it takes 0.03s

Answer (score 11):

First, here's an image from the docs which we'll use for testing:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzkJM.png"]
```

[image: jellyfish]

Going with the definition given in the IPP docs, here is a remapping method based on the use of `ImageValue[]`:

```
Options[ImageRemap] = {Padding -> 0, Resampling -> "Bilinear"}; 
ImageRemap[img_Image, xm_?MatrixQ, ym_?MatrixQ, opts : OptionsPattern[]] /; 
Reverse[ImageDimensions[img]] == Dimensions[xm] == Dimensions[ym] :=
        Module[{h, w}, {w, h} = ImageDimensions[img];
               Image[Partition[ImageValue[img,
                                          Flatten[Transpose[{ym, h - xm} - 1/2,
                                                            {3, 1, 2}], 1], 
                                          DataRange -> Full, opts,
                                          Options[ImageRemap]], w]]]
```

I don't know if there is a better way of doing this, but this implementation at least inherits the `Padding` and `Resampling` options of `ImageValue[]`, which may be needed for some mapping applications.

Let's try it out:

```
{w, h} = ImageDimensions[img];
mx = Array[Plus, {h, w}]; my = Array[BitXor, {h, w}];
ImageRemap[img, mx, my, Padding -> GrayLevel[3/4], Resampling -> "Lanczos"]
```

[image: jellyfish after remapping]