# How to remap a fisheye image?

Tags: image-processing

I want to flatten a series of fisheye images by remapping them to a rectinlinear projection.

To achieve this, I need to be able to remap the pixels of the image using fisheye correction formulas for the x-, and y-coordinates. How can I achieve this? 
I have found [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31274/how-can-i-efficiently-remap-an-image) and [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5676/how-to-peel-the-labels-from-marmalade-jars-using-mathematica) but I wonder how to use this for fisheye correction.

So far I've tried to use ImageTransformation for this, but I can't get the function to work properly.

```
  f[pt_] := With[{s = {.5, .5}},
  Module[{rd, polarcoor, ru, newcoor},
   rd = Norm[pt - s]^2/Norm[s];
   polarcoor = 
    CoordinateTransform[{"Cartesian" -> "Polar", 2}, (pt - s)];
   ru = 1*Tan[2*ArcSin[((polarcoor[[1]])/(2*1))]];
   CoordinateTransform["Polar" -> "Cartesian", {ru, polarcoor[[2]]}]
   ]
  ]
ImageTransformation[image,f]
```

This should first translate the image coordinates to polar coordinates, then calculate the new r (ru=r undistorted), and than translate these back to cartesian coordinates. 
The `ru = 1*Tan[2*ArcSin[((polarcoor[[1]])/(2*1))]]` is based on the above links, with a random value chosen as f. It fi

I get an error message, saying the function doesn't map. Anyone have an idea how to fix this and any further suggestions on how to improve the code?

[image: Example fisheye image]

**Update 2 22-10-2013**
Changed the code to:

```
image = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDX9f.jpg"];
r[pt_] := Module[{rd, ru, polarcoor, a},
  rd = Norm[pt];
  ru = *Transformation formula* 
  a = ArcTan @@ (pt);
  ru {Cos[a], Sin[a]}
  ]
```

Using `ru = Sqrt[rd];` 
`ImageTransformation[image, r, DataRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]` gives
[image]

Using `ru = ArcTan[rd];` 
`ImageTransformation[image, r, DataRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}]` gives
[image]

Both look like a step in the right direction, with straightened lines, but I got them by trial-and-error so I don't know the correctness.

Comment: your function must always return a position. Your `CoordinateTransform[]`s are failing for some values ("incompatible with the coordinate assumptions of the specified coordinate chart")

Comment: Seems to work if you evaluate `f` symbolically, e.g. `g[{x_, y_}] = f[{x, y}]; ImageTransformation[image, g]`

Comment: re your latest update - try restarting your kernel, it doesn't misbehave here.

Comment: @cormullion: Still not working here. Strange.

Answer (score 31):

It seems to me that your radial remapping is working okay, but the original image appears to have an asymmetric distortion, in that the vertical lines of the buildings converge towards a point which is slightly up from the centre of the image. I think it will be necessary to correct for that before doing the radial remapping. Here's a simple attempt to do the correction.

```
image = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDX9f.jpg"] ~ImagePad~ -7;

f[c_][{x_, y_}] := Module[{θ, ϕ},
  ϕ = ArcTan[x, y];
  θ = π/2 Sqrt[x^2 + y^2];
  c (1 - Sin[θ]) + 2 θ/π {Cos[ϕ], Sin[ϕ]}]

ImageTransformation[image, f[{0, 0.2}], 
 DataRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]
```

[image]

I think this is an improvement, though far from perfect. Of course it all comes down to knowing the form of the distortion.

**Original answer**

I misunderstood the aim of the question and provided a transformation which unrolls the fisheye image into a panorama. I will leave it here as it attracted a good number of upvotes so I assume it is of interest.

```
f[x0_, y0_][{th_, r_}] := (1 - 2 r/Pi) ({Sin[th], Cos[th]} - {x0, y0}) + {x0, y0}

ImageTransformation[image, f[0, 0.2], 
 DataRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, PlotRange -> {{0, 2 Pi}, {0, Pi/2}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Different way than I've been thinking (see update): For fish-eye undistortion, the radius from image centre to a pixel must be corrected. So I've tried to find that radius (by getting polar coordinates), apply a function to it and than translate the new polar coordinates back to Cartesian. Not getting it to work so far though.

Comment: I am not looking for a way to make panorama images, which is basically what you have achieved. Looks nice though!

Comment: @ErikP, sorry - I misunderstood the aim of the remapping. This must be the highest number of upvotes I've ever had for an answer which utterly fails to answer the question!

Comment: no problem, but do you have any ideas on how to solve the question, or give my current solution a nudge in the right direction?

Comment: @ErikP, I'll have another look. The asymmetry of the distortion makes it more complicated than it otherwise would be...

Comment: I'm not looking for a solution for this picture in particular, more of a general approach to flatten fisheye images, with some adjustable parameters for different image/camera types. I'm having a hard time finding suitable remapping formulas.

Answer (score 2):

"Fisheye projection" can mean [multiple different things](http://michel.thoby.free.fr/Fisheye_history_short/Projections/Fisheye_projection-models.html).  The most common projection used by lenses is the equal-area one, for which you were using a formula:

$$ r = 2f\sin(\theta/2) $$

Here $\theta$ is the angle under which a point is visible and $r$ is the distance of that point's projection from the optical axis on the image plane.  Please see the link above for a sketch of the coordinate system.  The parameter $f$ is the focal length of the lens, but for our purposes it just controls the radius of the 180-degree circle on the image plane.

The image you posted doesn't look like a true fisheye photo.  It looks like it is a stitched panorama.  You can see the stitching artefacts.  Thus there is a chance that it doesn't use equal area projection.  For simplicity I'm going to assume that it uses an equi-angular projection, i.e. $r = f\theta$.

To remap the image to a rectilinear projection, let us first choose a coordinate system as follows:

- put the origin in the middle
- let the half-width of the image be 1

We achieve this with `DataRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}` in `ImageTransformation`.

Choose a transformation function:

```
trafo = Function[{theta}, 2 Sin[theta/2]]; (* equal area *)

trafo = Function[{theta}, theta]; (* equi-angular *)
```

Let us set `f` now.  If the 180-degree image circle filled out the frame, it would be

```
f = 1/trafo[Pi/2];
```

But it's clear from looking at the image that the field of view is larger than 180 degrees.  We can see the ground in all directions. (BTW this is also a strong indicator that this is not a real fisheye image, as greater than 180-degree FoV lenses are rare.) So the radius of a 180-degree circle is less than `1`.  With some experimentation I found that `0.75` gives good results.

```
f = 0.75/trafo[Pi/2];
```

Load the image:

```
fishImg = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDX9f.jpg"]
```

f = 0.75/trafo[Pi/2];

Transform:

```
ImageTransformation[
 fishImg,
 Function[{px},
  With[{r = Norm[px]},
   trafo[ArcTan[r/f]] f/r px
   ]
  ],
 DataRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}},
 PlotRange -> 2 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The crop of the resulting image is set using `PlotRange`.

You can experiment with other projection functions too and see if you'll get better results.  There won't be a large difference though.