# Would it be possible to create spherical .hdr files in Mathematica?

Tags: animation

If I want to incorporate a 3D model created in Mathematica to a realistic environment in Cinema 4D to obtain something like this

[image: Fractal Torus]

I use a .hdr file in the Environment Settings, the preview of which typically looks like this

[image: Preview]

I think that these files are somehow created from multiple photos taken from different angles and then somehow "spehrically transformed or merged". I would like to be able to create my own .hdr file, say with pictures of my friends that would finally reflect in some 3D model (e.g. I have a friend whose name in English means "Teapot", so I would create a detailed model of a teapot in Mathematica, there is one such way how to create extremelly detailed model of the teapot in Wolfram Demonstrations, and his photo would reflect in the teapot--it would be funny :) )

So my question is this: Does anybody know how these "spherical" .hdr files are created and how it would be possible to create them in Mathematica? Thank you in advance for your suggestions and comments.

Comment: This is something which will most certainly be possible, but extremely difficult. It's basically a reverse of a kind of this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34264/how-to-remap-a-fisheye-image/34505#34505 but more complicated.