# How to get ImageTransformation to not compute the function at *every* pixel

Tags: functions, performance-tuning, image-processing, interpolation

I am using `ImageTransformation` with a slow function. Is there a way to get `ImageTransformation` to compute the function at only a few pixels, and then interpolate the function values for pixels in between?

For example, if $f((0,0))=(1,0)$, and $f((0,0.1))=(.9,.9)$, then it would assign the pixel at $(0,0.05)$ to the pixel at $(.95,.95)$.

Note that it should using every pixel of the input image (if warranted), it just shouldn't calculate the function for each pixel of the output image.

Comment: How about [remapping](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31274)?

Comment: @J.M. maybe. It looks like some sort of interpolation function might work too.